# Windows resolution only up to 1024x768 after installing OpenSuse

Tags: windows-7, linux, resolution, opensuse, grub2

I installed OpenSuse 13.1 in a 5yo laptop I had around with Windows 7. It was working fine with 1280x900.

OpenSuse cannot go further than 1024x768, but what is really surprising, is that Windows 7 cannot go further anymore right after installing Suse. Only 800x600 and 1024x768 are shown as possible options, and the screen is detected as "Digital Flat Panel (1024x768 60Hz)". The Intel driver utility does not show any other resolution available.

I am a little bit lost with this, because I don´t think it is a x.org thing. The laptop is a Dell XPS M1330 with a Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset Family. All drivers and both operating systems are up to date.

May it be a GRUB thing?

Comment: Grub is not the reason verify the display drivers are current and your not in VGA mode

Comment: Cross posted to U&L SE site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137229/after-installing-opensuse-13-1-my-computer-cannot-do-more-resolution-than-1024x